# Display certain variable of each object into a Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Quick question..

I have a List of objects of this class:

```
public class Whatever
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<blaBla> m_blaBla { get; set; }
    // ..
}
```

And I want to link the `List<Whatever>` to a ComboxBox, where the user sees the `Name` of each `Whatever` object. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either use `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` like this:

C#:

```
List<Whatever> lst = new List<Whatever>();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cmb.ItemsSource = lst;
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmb">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Or use [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<ComboBox Name="cmb" DisplayMemberPath="Name">            
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just override the `ToString()` function and it will do the job for you:

```
public class Whatever
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<blaBla> m_blaBla { get; set; }
    // ..
    public override string ToString()
    {
       return Name;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
List<Whatever> MyList = new List<Whatever>();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyComboBox.ItemsSource = MyList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Viewmodel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Whatever> WhCol
{
    get { return this.Name; }
    set { }
}
```

And then a Matching View

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding WhCol}" />
```

According to [Model-View-Modelview Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)

This is more suited if you wan't to make changes based on user input. (Which is kinda rare for a combobox).